# How to remove a line containing two specific string in text?

Tags: python, text-files

```
def deletematerial():
    print('Deleting of material ')
    fh_r = open("AQUESTO.txt", "r")
    name = input('Enter the name of de material to eliminate: ').lower()
    priority = input('the material is of low or high: ')
    print("\n")
    with open("bb.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in fh_r:
            if (name and priority not in line.strip("\n")):
                output.write(line)

    fh_r.close()
    os.remove("AQUESTO.txt")
    os.replace('bb.txt', 'AQUESTO.txt')
```

So if my text file have two same words:

---

```
name     |  priority
gun      |  low
granade  |  high
gun      |  high
```

and I put that I want to delete:

```
name: gun
priority: high
```

The second gun on the list, there should be the only thing that is deleting

When I delete, the file only deletes the ones that have just priority of high:

---

```
name    |   priority
gun     |   low
```

I want the file like this:

---

```
name     |  priority
gun      |  low
grenade  |  high
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you want *skip* lines with the `name` and `priority` words in them i.e. `(A and B)`, or to put it conversely `not (A and B)` which is equal to `(not A) or (not B)`<sup>✶</sup>, i.e. in order to *keep* those without `name` in the line or those that do have it, but don't have the `priority` word in them, . Here's how to write code that does that (using the latter logic to decide when to write copy lines). I also streamlined the code in your question somewhat by using `with` to open both the files *simultaneously* — so their closing will be done automatically. I also removed the unneeded `os.remove()`.

<sup>✶</sup>[De Morgan’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) transformation rules of logic.

```
import os

def delete_material():
    print('Deleting of material ')
    name = input('Enter the name of the material to eliminate: ').lower()
    priority = input('the material is of low or high: ').lower()
    print("\n")

    with open("AQUESTO.txt", "r") as fh_r, open("bb.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in fh_r:
            if name not in line or priority not in line:
                output.write(line)

    os.replace('bb.txt', 'AQUESTO.txt')  # Replace original file with updated version.


delete_material()
print('fini')
```

Answer (score 1):

`and` operator is not correctly handle in your code.
See for the reference:

```
>>> name="a"
>>> priority="high"
>>> name and priority
'high'
>>> "a" and "high"
'high'
>>> "high" and "A"
'A'
```

In order to clearly handle the code correctly split the condition into two separate check.
e.g

```
with open("bb.txt", "w") as output:
    for line in fh_r:
        words=line.strip("\n")
        if (name not in words) and (priority not in words):
            output.write(line)
```